# Fine-tuning of jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/)
to display some XML data I have coming in with combo boxes for filtering, but when I select a value, it doesn't seem to fire the event that reloads the grid.  This is my jQuery code on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {


    <!-- Sorting and pagination -->
    var oTable = $('#mainTable').dataTable( {
      "bJQueryUI": true,
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
      "bFilter": false
    });

    <!-- Filtering -->
    $("thead td").each(function(i) {
      this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect(oTable.fnGetColumnData(i));
      $('select', this).change(function() {
        oTable.fnFilter($(this).val(), i);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Additionally, I have added these functions to the bottom of jquery.dataTables.js as follows from this page: http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

```
(function ($) {
/*
* Function: fnGetColumnData
* Purpose:  Return an array of table values from a particular column.
* Returns:  array string: 1d data array 
* Inputs:   object:oSettings - dataTable settings object. This is always the last argument past to the function
*           int:iColumn - the id of the column to extract the data from
*           bool:bUnique - optional - if set to false duplicated values are not filtered out
*           bool:bFiltered - optional - if set to false all the table data is used (not only the filtered)
*           bool:bIgnoreEmpty - optional - if set to false empty values are not filtered from the result array
* Author:   Benedikt Forchhammer <b.forchhammer /AT\ mind2.de>
*/
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnGetColumnData = function (oSettings, iColumn, bUnique, bFiltered, bIgnoreEmpty) {
    // check that we have a column id
    if (typeof iColumn == "undefined") return new Array();

    // by default we only wany unique data
    if (typeof bUnique == "undefined") bUnique = true;

    // by default we do want to only look at filtered data
    if (typeof bFiltered == "undefined") bFiltered = true;

    // by default we do not wany to include empty values
    if (typeof bIgnoreEmpty == "undefined") bIgnoreEmpty = true;

    // list of rows which we're going to loop through
    var aiRows;

    // use only filtered rows
    if (bFiltered == true) aiRows = oSettings.aiDisplay;
    // use all rows
    else aiRows = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster; // all row numbers

    // set up data array    
    var asResultData = new Array();

    for (var i = 0, c = aiRows.length; i < c; i++) {
        iRow = aiRows[i];
        var aData = this.fnGetData(iRow);
        var sValue = aData[iColumn];

        // ignore empty values?
        if (bIgnoreEmpty == true && sValue.length == 0) continue;

        // ignore unique values?
        else if (bUnique == true && jQuery.inArray(sValue, asResultData) > -1) continue;

        // else push the value onto the result data array
        else asResultData.push(sValue);
    }

    return asResultData;
} 
} (jQuery));


function fnCreateSelect(aData) {
var r = '<select><option value=""></option>', i, iLen = aData.length;
for (i = 0; i < iLen; i++) {
    r += '<option value="' + aData[i] + '">' + aData[i] + '</option>';
}
return r + '</select>';
}
```

When I set a breakpoint in fnFilter and change the value of one of the filter drop-down boxes, the breakpoint does not get hit, but it does get hit when I set one in fnCreateSelect.  Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

If I use:

```
1    var oTable = $('#mainTable').dataTable( {
2       "oLanguage": {
3         "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
4       },
5       "bJQueryUI": true,
6       "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
7       "bFilter": false                                
8    });
```

.. the pagination doesn't work, but if I leave out lines 2-4, the filtering doesn't work.  Ugh!  Any thought, anyone?  Bueller?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reload the grid put this in the code where you want to reload:

```
oCache.iCacheLower = -1;
oTable.fnDraw();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like my program is not hitting the fnFilter function.  I've tried adding your code but to no avail.  Thanks again.  Music handles unite!